# What does this sentence mean ? "Heaven and earth, are the shades of Pemberley to be thus polluted?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Pride and Prejudice, when an old woman (Catherine) asks a young lady (Elizabeth) whether she is engaged with her nephew or not, the young lady neither confirms nor rejects such relationship in a dissembling way.
Lady Catherine censures Elizabeth and criticizes the scandalous elopement of her sister. Then she says this sentence:

> Heaven and earth! Are the shades of Pemberley to be thus polluted?

What does it really mean?

Comment: _shades of Pemberley_ is googleable: http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/dailylifeaspects/qt/RomanGhosts.htm

Comment: [Austen’s use of the word “shades” has generated many theories and some research into the word does little to clarify.](http://janeausteninvermont.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/book-review-pemberley-shades/). I think this question is therefore Off Topic Lit Crit (or Primarily Opinion-Based, take your pick).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is litcrit. Though the several meanings of the words could be debated, the author's intention/ implication is for the individual reader to fathom.

Comment: @Kris, It looks like some users of this site harbor a strong ambition for closing questions... All I'm asking is the meaning of the phrase in plain English. Does this post really seems to you,I don't know, faint?

Comment: "Litcrit" and narrative speculation would be to go further in analysis than 'what does this mean' (in plain English). To me litcrit would involve some _further_ psychological or _deeper_ metaphorical interpretation.

Comment: In the given context, the reader is **not** expected to understand the sentence from dictionary definitions alone. Else all literature would be vain. I'm sure you agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my interpretation:

Preserving structure while modernising and clarifying as much as possible,

> "Heaven and earth! Are the shades of Pemberley to be thus polluted?"

becomes

> Heaven's above! (a softer form of "Oh God!") Is this how the family line of Pemberley  will get corrupted? (referring to intermarriage with someone deemed unworthy)

(Original reply follows)

There seems to be a very thorough answer [here](http://austenprose.com/2008/09/07/pemberley-shades-pride-and-prejudice-continues-by-d-a-bonavia-hunt-a-review/).

But in a nutshell, I think it's as @Vilmar suggests, though perhaps more another way of saying that the family (via the evocative use of long dead ancestors through 'shades') will be tainted by the intermarriage.

EDIT: Why do I get the sense the speaker is worried that the family line will be tainted in the near future? Because *Heaven and Earth!* seems to be a statement of dismay or worry, like "goodness gracious!" or "Gosh no!" And the phrase *to be* indicates the future; *thus polluted*, tainted.

Comment: What does "heaven and earth" mean? Why did the Lady used "thus pollured" if the marriage had not taken place yet?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator. *Heaven and Earth!* seems like 'goodness gracious'. *To be* thus polluted - a future tense.

Comment: I should at that 'to be thus' can be taken as future or present, but if the marriage hasn't happened, I would take the context into account as future. I would read it that way for want of better background knowledge anyway; as an attempt at simple literal meaning.

Answer (score 3):

"Shades" here most likely refer to the ghosts of Pemberley (its ancestors). Lady Catherine is thus worried that an "unsuitable" person will soon join these ghosts.